# What is the Vanilla JS meaning of this construction used in Svelte?

Tags: javascript

The Svelte [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) presents line

```
$: doubled = count * 2;
```

And claims

> [..]  It's valid (if unconventional) JavaScript [..]

If it's valid in plain JavaScript, what's the meaning of it?

I tried it in the console and `$: tt = 5` seems to assign a value of `5` to `tt` but does nothing to `$`. It also seems that I can place other strings at the start like `fdf: ddd = 44` and it works the same.

Note: I am NOT asking about the role of this in Svelte but in plain JS without Svelte compiler.

Comment: The string of characters before the `:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for a label. It is typically used if you have nested loops and you want to break out of the further out loop:

```
loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         break loop1; // this exits out of both loops
      }
      break loop2; // this leaves only the inner "j" loop
      break;       // This does the same thing as "break loop2"
   }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label for more reference information.

Comment: Is there any meaning to label a declaration? It seems that placing `loop1: x = 5` at the start (or anywhere else) makes the label unusable (undefined) at every other line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, having a label there doesn't change the assignment in anyway (in non-svelte javascript). It is exactly _because_ this label syntax is allowed in too many places that it was "up for grabs" for svelte to safely reuse it.